# Running batch file from location of context menu right click

Tags: batch-file, menu, registry

Greetings dear developers,

I wrote a batch file to automatically add an exception in the windows firewall (both in and out) using the netsh advfirewall command and set the program parameter to the %cd% variable.

I added my batch file to the context menu by adding a registry key under HKCR*\shell, with the name of my batch file and under that, a key named command with the following value data in the `(Default)` key: `C:\"Batch file location" %1`

However, I want it to run on the location of the right-click context menu on a file I right click. Just like how you can "run cmd here" (in the location you right-click), I want my batch file to run on the location of that context menu.

What do I need to change? Do I need to change the program parameter? Or do I need to add an extra value/key in the registry.

Please point out my mistake and if you want any further details let me know.

Edit: Here is my batch file, as requested:

Edit 2: removed elevation script

```
@echo off
title Firewall Exceptions Creator
pause
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="%cd%" dir=in program="%cd%" profile=any action=block
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="%cd%" dir=out program="%cd%" profile=any action=block
pause
```

Also, I want to right click on top of an .exe file and I want the command prompt  to know the exact location and the file that I right clicked, and use that location in the "program=" argument.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We can only tell you what you need to change after you've provided exactly what you have! Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63729019/edit), to provide your code, properly formatted. You should also properly explain where exactly you'd like to click and what you'd like it to pass to the command when you do.

Comment: Your location at right click invoke time will be passed as an argument to the script, so your script would need to be modified to accept that argument. In addition to that I would advise that you get rid of all that elevation rubbish for now, _(there are too many issues with that anyhow, which would require a separate question)_, and just concentrate on getting the location to be transferred to the appropriate part of your command. Just to clarify, when the end user right clicks on a `.exe` file, do you want its parent directory location to be passed? not the file itself.

Comment: Alright, I will delete the elevation script for now. How do I add the seperate argument you mentioned?

Comment: I want either one to be transfered, im not sure which is appropriate. I want the one that will allow cmd to know what file I right clicked on. Could you explain what either of them offer/do?

Comment: I guess I want to have the path of the file and the filename transferred. I'm sorry but my knowledge is somewhat limited.

Comment: So you didn't want to use `"%CD%"` anyhow, with all of the bloat now removed, you'd probably want to use `"%~1"`. In addition to that, you've only provided a batch file you want to run when the context menu item is invoked, how have you created the menu item. I know you've done it, although I don't know if it is correct, because you mentioned `HKCR*\shell` directly in your question body. As the code is more complicated for creating that entry, you really need to include that too!

Comment: Ok then, thanks. I will try that. Could you please explain what it does? I also have "%1" at the end of the key value in my command key (referring to the registry entry I mentioned in the question)

Comment: No, once we have all of the information we need to provide a reliable solution with respect to your actual issue, someone will likely pop along to create an answer for you. However, please note, that whilst some members here are crazy enough to act as a tutor, and fully explain how their provided answers work, this site is not a one to one tutor/student site, so do not expect it.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I hope you can point to me a website so I can learn how %1 works. Also, one last question, how do I get only the filename to pass through to the `"name=" ` argument in the firewall command. You've been very helpful btw, thanks!

Comment: I have no intention of using a website for this, every command has built in help. For yours, open a Command Prompt window, type `call /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the information presented. So the full path would be `"%~1"` and the filename with extension would be `"%~nx1"`. I would still like you to provide the registry information you've set up for the context menu, getting the commands in the batch file correct is only part of the task, the registry part is no less important.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! Have a nice day good sir/madame!

Comment: ok,  i will provide it right away!

Comment: To begin with you should not use `HKCR`, you should use either `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes` for a context menu for every user, or `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes` for the current user. In addition to that you said that you wanted to right click on a exe file, so what makes you think that `\*` would be more appropriate than `\.exe`?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I haven't thought of creating it in `\.exe`. Why not use HKCR though?

Comment: If I add the key anywhere else (the other locations you mentioned) other than my current location it doesn't show up in the context menu

Comment: Well, I have no idea how you're doing it, so it's not easy for me to provide you with directions, but I can assure you that using `*` is not what you should be doing. If I was creating the context menu entry, I would do that directly from a [[tag:batch-file]], or [[tag:powershell]] script.

Comment: Sorry for me being inaccurate. I want to create it in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.exe`. Should I create another key in there, before creating the key named after my batch file?

Comment: Whilst I'm not here to tell you you're wrong with that decision, please take account that every single user on that PC will not need such a facility in their context menu. I've never needed it, nor do I recall ever having created such a thing on any of the thousands of units I've worked on. I would therefore ask you to consider not wasting unnecessary screen real estate for every single user, if you do not need them all to use that specific 'feature', and choose `HKCU` instead.

Comment: Ok, so `HKCU` it is. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes`, then?

Comment: I found it: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell`. I created the key here. Now the only thing remaining is elevating the batch file, you told me my initial script isn't appropriate?

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't appropriate, just that it had issues. Apart from that, now that you've worked out that your script is receiving `%1` as a parameter, you'll also notice that the elevation technique is also using `%1`, and that may very well cause additional issues too.